# AccessibilityService stops receiving events on reboot

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I have an app that uses the accessibility services to listen to notifications. It works correctly unti the user reboots. If you reboot, you have to disable/re-enable the service from the accessibility services menu.

Why does the app not get the events after a reboot?

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    pMan = new PreferencesManager(this);
    bulbManager = new BulbManager(((Context) this), pMan.getBridge());
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    setServiceInfo(info);
    Log.d("OMG, STARTED FINALLY!", "RIGHT NOW!");
}
```

and the xml

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
    android:packageNames="com.t3hh4xx0r.huenotifier"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:settingsActivity="com.t3hh4xx0r.huenotifier.activities.LoadingSplashActivity"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="false"
    android:description="@string/app_name" />
```

and the manifest

```
   <service
        android:name="com.t3hh4xx0r.huenotifier.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/service_info" />
    </service>
```

Comment: What about this problem?

Comment: What was the exact version of Android that you had this problem in?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem. After a lot of attempt I found that this problem occurs with older version of android (eg.Jellybean). when device is powered off the service gets unbinded. But it is not rebinded `on_Boot_Completed`. As this problem doesn't appear on newer version of android I considered it as a android bug. Because only way to re-activate the service is turning off and restarting the service, I am using `sharedPreference` to keep track states of my service. when `onUnbind` `onRebind` or `onServiceConnected` is called I update my `sharedPreference` with the value I associated for it. Now, before using service I check that if the service called `onRebind` or `onServiceConnected` if not then I tell user to restart service or start working with my service.

If you are so confused then you can Include the bellow code in your accessibility service.

```
public static String AccessibilityPreference="AccessibilityPreference";
public static String isServiceBinded="isServiceBinded";
@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    Log.e(TAG, "ACC::onServiceConnected:************************* ");
    SharedPreferences p=getSharedPreferences(AccessibilityPreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e=p.edit();
    e.putBoolean(isServiceBinded,true);
    e.commit();
}
 @Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("onUnbind","onUnbind Called***************************************************");
    SharedPreferences p=getSharedPreferences(AccessibilityPreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e=p.edit();
    e.putBoolean(isServiceBinded,false);
    e.commit();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("onRebind","onRebind Called***************************************************");
    SharedPreferences p=getSharedPreferences(AccessibilityPreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e=p.edit();
    e.putBoolean(isServiceBinded,true);
    e.commit();
    super.onRebind(intent);
}
public static boolean isServiceBinded(SharedPreferences preferences){
   return preferences.getBoolean(isServiceBinded,true);
}
```

Then before start working with the service check if service is valid like bellow,

```
if(AccessibilityWorkService.isServiceBinded(getSharedPreferences(AccessibilityWorkService.AccessibilityPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE))){
//start working
}else {
//tell user to restart service
}
```