# Accessibility service is not working properly when device booted after power off

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api, accessibility

I have used `AccessibilityService` on my App to automatically Force stop Apps I desire to. Everything works fine unless I power off my phone. After turning my phone on `AccessibilityService` doesn't work properly. It doesn't call `onAccessibilityEvent` mathod until I turn off and restart My accessibility from settings. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28053444/6697154) answer, telling that it can be validated by using log in onDestroy. Can anyone explane how to do this, or how can I solve my problem..?

Comment: I have used Log in onDestroy but it is not showed on log cat when powered off. So I think the answer is 'NO'.

Comment: 498 pid=5608
   Client:
       nothing to dump   No difference between the output found when the service was working.