# No callbacks from AccessibilityService on locked Android

Tags: android

Next code stopped working in Android 8.1 when smartphone is locked (display is black)

it only works if phone is unlocked

In Android 8.0 I remember next code was working always

```
<service
    android:label="@string/accessibility_service_name"
    android:name=".WindowChangeDetectingService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice"/>
</service>
```

My AccessibilityService class

```
public class WindowChangeDetectingService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();

        //Configure these here for compatibility with API 13 and below.
        AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;

        setServiceInfo(config);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
            if (event.getPackageName() != null && event.getClassName() != null) {
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                        event.getPackageName().toString(),
                        event.getClassName().toString()
                );
                Log.i("Component", componentName.flattenToShortString() + " " + componentName.getShortClassName());
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Cause such feature I need only for my phone I found next solution:

> Options / Security & Location / Screen lock / None

(Select **None**)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `onAccessibilityEvent` isn't calledm it's only called if Phone display is active (not black)

Comment: @Khemraj when I press power button and phone's display becomes black (phone is locked) then it stops working and `onAccessibilityEvent` is never called

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28053444/6891563

Comment: @Khemraj I selected **None** for **Screen lock** (`Options / Security & Location / Screen lock / None`) seems it works ok even if phone's display is turned off (black)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Service is being killed by OS due to **[Doze mode or Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).**

> In Doze mode, the system attempts to conserve battery by restricting apps' access to network and CPU-intensive services.

Now as solution for this you can check periodically (say by 2 hours) if your service is killed. Implement periodic task by **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)**. And restart service if killed.

Comment: ` check periodically (say by 2 hours)` - what do you mean? it's killed instantly after pressing power button (to lock phone)

Comment: See work manager link, you have to make another scheduler to check Accessibility service.