# AccessibilityService gets unbinded when powered off and is not rebinded after reboot

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api, accessibility

I am facing an issue with `AccessibilityService`. When I power off my device `AccessibilityService` gets unbinded by invoking `onUnbind`. But when I start my device again, `AccessibilityService` is not rebinded and `onRebind` service is not called. I have checked using adb command `adb shell dumpsys activity service  .MyPackage.AccessibilityService` and found my service is alive but is not receiving `AccessibilityEvent` as service is not rebounded. Everything starts working fine again after I stop and restart my AccessibilityService from settings. How can I fix this issue..? I though about using `disableself` at `onUnbind` that because it will force user to start the service from settings, but this call is available from `API 24` . So, what should I do..?

Comment: How many devices does this problem occur in?

Comment: I have tested my app only on 2 devices, One is Jellybean which creates the problem, other one is KitKat which works fine most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot and tried almost everything could be done. Finally I came to a conclusion that this is a android bug, as this problem is not occurring on `API 19` or later. For other developers who is suffering from this problem, I suggest you to use preference to store state of your service that it is `rebinded` or not. Now before you try to use your service check if your service is rebinded or not. If not, tell user that he/she will have to restart the service before using it.

I provided a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593680/6697154). check this out if you are still confused.